# How to remove the top shadow of a sheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I need to get rid of the shadow on top of a sheet:

[image]

I know it's being drawn in a special window, but I have no way to get to it. I tried:

- Looping through all windows filtered by the app with CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo and then looking them up by id with [NSApp windowWithWindowNumber:]. The window is in the list, but when I look it up by id I get nil back.
- Method swizzling for [NSWindow init], [NSWindow initWithRect...], [NSWindow setFrame:] but non of these get called by this magic window.

Comment: What API are you calling to produce this sheet?

Comment: Just [NSApp beginSheet:...] with a custom NSWindow.

Comment: In a perfect world I would be able to make my own sheet animations with this, but then I won't be able to get into the app store: https://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h

Comment: If you try to make your own sheet animation maybe this threads helps: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/280168-imitating-behavior-of-sheet-window.html

Comment: I just came across this answer while I was looking for a solution to this problem and it seems that there has been no progress in the past 3 years. Unfortunately, I also wasn't able to solve it. However, I want to share an additional detail: when you look up the the shadow window with `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, you can find it but you can't change it (e.g. hide). It seems that this window is totally inaccessible. This is esp. annoying if you want to change the sheet position away from the parent title-/toolbar. If anyone makes progress on this one, please let us know. kthxbye ;-)